# attaching multiple Elastic Inference accelerators with EC2 instance in AWS using AWS

Tags: terraform

Has any one worked with attaching multiple Elastic Inference accelerators with EC2 instance in AWS.
I am getting error while provisioning this scenario using terraform.

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "service" {
  name_prefix   = "***************"
  key_name             = "**************"
  image_id             = "**************"
  instance_type        = "**************"
  # security_groups      = "**************"
  vpc_security_group_ids = "**************"

  iam_instance_profile {
    name = "***************"

  user_data            = var.user_data
  
#attaching first accelrator
  elastic_inference_accelerator {
    type = var.ia_instance_type
  }

#attaching second accelrator
  elastic_inference_accelerator {
    type = var.ia_instance_type
  }

  }

}
```

Comment: What error do you get when you attempt to plan or apply that?

Comment: Error: List longer than MaxItems

  on ../../modules/service-ec2-IA-multi/main.tf line 9, in resource "aws_launch_template" "service":
   9: resource "aws_launch_template" "service" {

Attribute supports 1 item maximum, config has 2 declared